# How to enable CORS on server side using ng serve option

Tags: angular, cors, httpclient

I have a server side app Using Angular 7 and I need to see if there command line option, like so

```
ng serve --Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

There is quite a bit of online chatter about this but I'm hoping to have a good reference for that works with both Firefox and Chrome.

I did install this (as per one of the suggestions) but it doesn't help.

```
npm install ember-cli-cors
```

Comment: Do you have any mini GitHub repository for it? there should be an alternative way to do that. or at least add more details

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I cant post the code to github.
I am going with the proxy gateway approach to deal with CORS and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration to support **`CORS`**  should be done on the server side. There shouldn't be anything to set on the Angular client side.

However if you still want to do that, **[Refer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/803)**

Run the npm **[http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)** onto the public or dist folder directly.

It has these attributes:

**`http-server -o --cors`**

Also you can set a proxy by creating a proxy.config as mentioned **[here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/)**

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I am trying this on the server side.

I currently run `ng serve`. What are you suggesting that I try?